# Build MinGW Console application without CRT?

Tags: visual-c++, msvcrt, mingw-w64

I can build apps with MSVC without the CRT as directed here:

http://www.mvps.org/user32/nocrt.html

But how can this be done with MinGW? It seems to always pull in the CRT (msvcrt.dll) by default.

Edit: To be clear I'm trying to NOT link the CRT at ALL, not statically link it which I know isn't possible due to copyright issues.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can I link MSVCRT statically with mingw?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3943412/can-i-link-msvcrt-statically-with-mingw)

Comment: No I'm not trying to statically link, I'm trying to not link AT ALL as in no crt what so ever

Comment: Have you had any success?

Comment: so long ago  now, can't even recall if I got it working, probably not